# IntelliJ IDEA: two-finger touchpad scrolling does not work (KUbuntu, X11)

Tags: xorg, touchpad, scrolling, kubuntu, intellij-idea

I think this is a known issue since I see it on different laptops, but still does not google easily.

In IntelliJ IDEA, when I unplug mouse and use my (synaptics?) Lenovo touchpad under Linux, it won't scroll. Period. It won't vertical scroll in the source window, which is a killer.

Is there a way to make IDEA scroll under Linux/X11 when using touchpad, specifically the Lenovo kind?

Comment: Sometimes it does work mysteriously, but mostly doesn't.